# Приложение зависает на splash экране

Tags: android

Задача сделать сплеш скрин в приложении. Изначально у меня был такой код

```
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment{
SplashTask splashTask;

public SplashFragment() {}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    splashTask = new SplashTask();
    splashTask.execute();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false);
}

class SplashTask extends AsyncTask<View, View, View>{

    @Override
    protected View doInBackground(View... views) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Сплеш скрин висел две секунды и успешно открывалась активити, но случалась утечка памяти. Я воспользовалась слабой ссылкой и код теперь выглядит так

```
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {

public SplashFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new SplashTask((MainActivity) getActivity()).execute();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false);
}


public static class SplashTask extends AsyncTask<View, View, View> {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityWeakReference;
    private MainActivity activity;

   SplashTask(MainActivity context) {
        activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        activity = activityWeakReference.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected View doInBackground(View... views) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (activity != null) {
            activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

но теперь сплеш скрин зависает секунд на 10 и бывает, что только при нажатии кнопки назад на аппарате открывается активити. В чем может быть проблема?

метод в MainActivity

```
   public void runSplash() {
    SplashFragment splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.content_frame, splashFragment).
            addToBackStack(null).
            commit();
}
```

Comment: У вас очень плохая реализация сплеш скрина. Все делается гораздо проще.

Comment: Не используйте AsyncTask, он устарел

Comment: Реализация конкретно устаревшая. Сейчас можно создать сплэш скрин, используя лишь android `theme`. Сделайте отдельный Splash стиль унаследованный от `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, задайте в нем `background.xml`. Ну и в `manifest`'e, где находится `MainActivity` укажите SplashTheme. https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857